# UWP app incompatible with Windows 10 S support

Tags: uwp

I have converted a desktop app to UWP app using the msix packaging tool. I have submitted the app to the Windows app store. But the app was rejected because of the reason listed below.

This is the response I received from Microsoft:

> We have detected that your app is incompatible with Windows 10 S. Please update your app to support Windows 10 S if possible. Otherwise include a prominent statement anywhere in the Metadata that the app does not support Windows 10 S. This issue may affect merchandisability.
>
> Please be sure to test your app for Windows 10 S: https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-test-windows-s
>
> We could not test your app on Windows 10 S because the application terminates unexpectedly at launch.

Tested Devices: (Win 10 S) Microsoft Surface Laptop, Lenovo Ideapad 310T

Should I update my app to support windows 10 S -- and if yes, then what changes need to be done to support it -- or include a prominent statement in the metadata?

For the latter one, how to include a prominent statement in the metadata?

Answer (score 1):

> Should I update my app to support windows 10 S (If yes then what
>   changes needs to be done to support it) or include a prominent
>   statement in the metadata.

It is your decision to make. Maybe find the market share for S Mode and decide if it is worth a try. For the changes needed, you should run your app on Windows 10 S mode and fix the crashes.

> For the latter one how to include a prominent statement in the
>   metadata ?

You need to include something like "This app is not compatible with Windows 10 S Mode" in the description second of your app (Submission -> Store Listing -> Description) so it become visible to the users on MS Store.